# Java IO vs NIO, what is really difference?

Tags: java, networking, io, netty, nio

I'm quite fond of Java NIO and I really want to apply Java NIO to my current system, but when I created these samples application to compare between Java IO and NIO, it made me quite disappointed.

Here are my 2 samples (I don't put all the source code)

Java IO

```
public class BlockingServerClient {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(BlockingServerClient.class.getName());

    static final ExecutorService service = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        int port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

        BlockingServerClient server = new BlockingServerClient();

        Server sr = server.new Server(port);
        service.submit(sr);
    }

    private class Server implements Runnable {

        .....

        public void run() {
            ServerSocket ss = null;
            try {
                ss = new ServerSocket(localPort);
                log.info("Server socket bound to " + localPort);

                while (true) {
                    Socket client = ss.accept();
                    log.info("Accepted connection from " + client.getRemoteSocketAddress());

                    service.submit(new SocketClient(client));
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                log.log(Level.SEVERE, "Server error", e);
            } finally {
                .....
            }
        }
    }

    private class SocketClient implements Runnable {

        .....

        public void run() {
            InetSocketAddress addr = (InetSocketAddress) socket.getRemoteSocketAddress();
            socketInfo = String.format("%s:%s", addr.getHostName(), addr.getPort());

            log.info("Start reading data from " + socketInfo);
            try {
                in = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

                String input;
                while ((input = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    log.info(String.format("[%s] %s", socketInfo, input));

                    log.info("Socket " + socketInfo + " thread sleep 4s");
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(4);
                }

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                log.log(Level.SEVERE, "Socket error", ex);
            } finally {
                .....
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Java NIO

```
public class NonBlockingServerClient {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(NonBlockingServerClient.class.getName());

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

        EventLoopGroup boss = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        EventLoopGroup worker = new NioEventLoopGroup();

        try {
            NonBlockingServerClient sc = new NonBlockingServerClient();

            Server server = sc.new Server(port, boss, worker);

            server.run();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.log(Level.SEVERE, "Error", e);
        } finally {
            boss.shutdownGracefully();
            worker.shutdownGracefully();
        }
    }

    private class Server {

        .....

        public void run() {
            log.info("Start Server bootstrap");
            ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
            b.group(boss, worker)
             .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
             .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<Channel>() {

                @Override
                protected void initChannel(Channel ch) throws Exception {
                    ChannelPipeline pipe = ch.pipeline();
                    pipe.addLast(new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(8192, Delimiters.lineDelimiter()));
                    pipe.addLast(new StringDecoder());
                    pipe.addLast(new ClientHandler());
                }
            });

            ChannelFuture future = null;
            try {
                future = b.bind(port).sync();
                future.channel().closeFuture().sync();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                log.log(Level.SEVERE, "Server binding error", e);
                future.channel().close();
            }

        }
    }

    private class ClientHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<String> {

        @Override
        protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, String msg)
                throws Exception {
            log.info(String.format("[%s] %s", ctx.channel().remoteAddress(), msg));
            log.info(ctx.channel().remoteAddress() + " sleep 4s");
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(4);
        }

    }
}
```

Client

```
public class Client {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName());

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        int port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Client cl = new Client("localhost", port);
            cl.start();
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(500);
        }
    }

    String host;
    int port;

    public Client(String host, int port) {
        this.host = host;
        this.port =port;
    }

    public void start() {
        log.info("Start client running");
        Socket socket = null;
        String info = "";
        try {
            socket = new Socket(host, port);
            InetSocketAddress addr = (InetSocketAddress) socket.getLocalSocketAddress();
            info = String.format("%s:%s", addr.getHostName(), addr.getPort());
            int count = 10;

            OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
            while (count > 0) {
                String outStr = "Output-" + count + "\n";
                out.write(outStr.getBytes());
                out.flush();
                count--;
            }
            out.write((info + "-Finish sending").getBytes());
            out.flush();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.log(Level.SEVERE, "Client error", e);
        } finally {
            try {
                socket.close();
                log.info(info + "-Client close");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                log.log(Level.SEVERE, "Closing client error", e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Client when run will create 10 clients connect to the server. After I run and monitored several times, I found no different between Java IO and NIO.

If changed number of clients to 500, I found that the java IO really created 500 threads, however the consumption of data really fast. In contrast, the java NIO application had much fewer threads than the other, but the consumption of data was slow and it took longer time to finish everything.

So, what is really the benefit of Java NIO? Create fewer threads to save memory but slower in performance.

Or, I might did it wrongly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The speed difference that you are noticing is because of the 4s sleep that appears in both test cases.

In the non-NIO case, which has one thread per request, sleeping for 4 seconds only blocks that one request.  However in the NIO case, which has a far smaller number of worker threads, it blocks that request and every other request that is waiting to run on that thread.

So this begs the question, why would we want to use less threads with the NIO approach?  And the answer is scalability. Modern Operating Systems have a scaling problem related to the number of threads blocked on network IO.  See the [C10K](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C10k_problem) problem for more details.

In general I do find NIO to be faster, or at least it has the potential to be much faster if:

1. You use it to avoid copying buffers around
2. And you avoid anything that can block the threads.  eg do not block
   on a database fetch etc.

This is where async frameworks like [akka](http://akka.io/) shine.

Comment: As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46965752/3317808), NIO- Non blocking IO, is a single threaded programming model that involves `select()` system call internally. Am not sure, why we compare threaded blocked IO with threaded NIO.